# How to communicate between multiple windows of the same chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

When using chrome developer tools, it appears that each app window (and the background 'page') has its own javascript context (space of objects, thread of execution), and yet the createdWindow callback of chrome.app.window.create apparently provides direct access to the objects of the 'other' window that was just created.

Given that, I'm unclear on the best way to communicate between windows; e.g. if I open a second window to act as a dialog box, when the user clicks OK to save changes, should I be using postMessage, sendMessage, or just call a function on an object in the main window. I've looked at the messaging samples, and they seem focused on communication between two different apps, or between an app and an extension.

So, I'm seeking a clear description of the memory and execution model within one app. Are there really separate contexts, or is it just one space of objects, with one thread of execution?  What is the best way to communicate between windows of the same chrome app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a great question James!

Multiple chrome windows are not completely separate. They share a single thread and object space, however the window object is different for each. In javascript unscoped references to things are looked up on the current window, so this makes the windows appear to be different object spaces - but they are not really.

So, you can reach into another window and execute a function there, or manipulate state in other ways (e.g. set a variable on another window to a function from the current window) and it is acceptable and supported.

Comment: Thanks.  May I assume from your answer that the global (unscoped?) references to "window" or "chrome" are based on a scope for the window in which the <script> tag is located, so that a function in another window will see its "own" window, not the window of the caller?

Comment: That is true if the script is only in one window, however scripts can be listed in multiple windows. To work out what the global context / window is (chrome hangs off window, btw) the following rules apply (1) if you're not in a closure, what is the originating global context (i.e. what global context was in place when the event or callback or whatever fired) and (2) if you are in a closure, what iwas the global context when the window was created.

Comment: Following on from the above, I'm sure it is actually more complicated than that, given that this is javascript and full of [insanity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @BenWells I asked a follow-up question based on your answer here - hope you are able to shed some light on it too if you have a chance... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819384/why-does-a-new-developer-tools-window-open-for-each-chrome-app-window

Comment: Must chrome.app.window.create be invoked within a background page or any Window page (JS) is able to call it? I try to invoke a from a normal JavaScript, but an error pops up saying the URL of the page is not found.

Comment: @Be, **Citation needed** for "*Multiple chrome windows are not completely separate*".

Answer (score 3):

You might find the [chrome.app.window.getAll()](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#method-getAll) and [chrome.app.window.get()](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#method-get) methods useful. They are however new to Chrome 33 which is not yet in the stable channel.

As an alternative you could hold an array of opened `AppWindow` objects in the background page context.

You can then get a reference to the background page context from any window using the [chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage) method

Comment: You're quite correct, but the focus of my question isn't about how to get the AppWindow instance of a particular window, but rather what is the best way (or good alternatives) to send information to the other windows? If I just reach into another window and execute a function, does it act as if it is running in the origin window, or the other window? Or is that just a stupid question because (maybe?) there is really only a single Javascript thread of execution for a chrome web app?