# Why does a new Developer Tools window open for each Chrome App window?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Following on from this question: [How to communicate between multiple windows of the same chrome app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765870/how-to-communicate-between-multiple-windows-of-the-same-chrome-app) and answer, is this why when you are developing an app that you have loaded via 'load unpacked extension' and open a new window using `chrome.app.window.create()` and then right-click on the new window to 'Inspect Element' you get a *new* developer tools window and not the one already open for the original window of the chrome app? Or is it a bug?

I ask because its very time-consuming having to switch between the different developer tools windows when I'm actually using Dev Tools (with Workspaces) as the actual IDE for writing my Chrome app (I am *not* using any other external text editor or IDE)

Comment: I do not quite get your question. One dev tools window can only attach to one tab, and does not switch to a new one if you open one.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but in regards to chrome apps, the question i linked to suggests that all windows of a chrome app share the same JS global context so i would have thought they could share a single dev tools instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of dev tools in Chrome. What is being suggested would be pretty cool, but it would need some work that we haven't done.

Just to be clear, different windows do not share the same JS "global context". The quotes are there because the "global context" is a thing, it has a real meaning.

Imagine there are two windows A and B, and they live in the same JS universe. All the objects in the universe are accessible to both windows, if they can get a reference. There will be two window objects, windowA and windowB.

"Global context" refers to which window object unscoped identifiers are looked for in.

When running code in the "global context" of window A, unscoped identifiers will be looked up in the context of windowA. E.g. "foo" will be looked for on windowA.foo. If foo is actually on windowB it won't be found. Put another way, if you create a global variable while running code in the "global context" of window A, it will actually be put on windowA. If you then run code in the global context of window B, you will need to have a reference to windowA to be able to access it.

I hope that makes sense; it is kind of hard to explain. I've probably got some finer points of it wrong as well.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @Ben makes perfect sense when you point out that the global contexts for each window are in fact different even if they can be accessed by diff windows.

Comment: I get that logic as, (app) background page is the same as extension background page with it's own dev window, and every chrome.app.window is created with some HTML page, and just like content scripts in tabs, those app windows need (and have) their own environment and own dev windows. The only tricky/buggy thing is that I don't see button/link to dev window of my app window when it's fired. Only when I open app bg page dev window, button is created... uhmmm messy to even explain it :)

Comment: Outside of the apps Chrome is faster than Firefox though it's GUI (mostly lack thereof and zero real customization) kills the time saved because of speedy page loads whereas Firefox (can be if you're really crafty due to all the junk they keep adding) exceptionally customizable however you lose time because it's so bogged down memory wise. It would be *incredibly* helpful to have a *single* dev tools window that switches to whatever tab/app/etc is focused on, perhaps treat windows as layers. Please do it before I get rich and just end up doing it myself. :-)